# Connecting domain and application logic to present entities in the UI

Tags: react-native, domain-driven-design

For the first i want to sorry for my english. I'm learning domain driven design and trying to implement some concepts in an application i'm working on. My task is not so complex to fully implement DDD on all the levels but i really like it's principles and the core idea and try to use it.

Lets say app is selling books. So i have a Book entity and BooksCollection or BooksRepository. I'm working on frontend and that collection or updates to it is coming from server. And i want to represent it on BooksScreen in BooksList which consists of BookCard. Press on that card for the first calls something like selectBook which changes the selectedBookId in collection and for the second navigates user to BookDetails screen where the data of selected book is represented and the user can do some actions related to domain logic.

The first question is where do i put the loading state of that BooksCollection and according actions to change it ? Loading state is not a domain logic as i understand, it's not an entity status like "todo done" or something. But i need to show a loading indicator in the UI list when the collection updates, error for loading error and success respectively.

And the second is where do i put the the same loading state for single Book ?
I separate it cause for collection i may store that state in some application related class e.g. "BooksScreenState" or something with less stupid name. But what if i decide to show state for each specific card in the UI e.g. that specific card failed to load. Or i have a single User in app and his data can be loading, he can be authorized or not et cetera.

So i can summarize that to something like "how to connect domain and application logic to present a UI".

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question. I don't usually think to apply DDD to the UI level because for the most part, the UI isn't full of business rules and also because I mostly use reactjs and UI frameworks are usually very prescriptive and don't allow much in the way of flexibility.

To answer your question though: If you did want to get a "loading" status in your UI (that's designed using DDD), it'd have to be attached to a "View" object or some representation of the "view"; because that fits the UL (ubiquitous language) better. Think of how you have described it in a little snippet of your question:

> But what if i decide to show state for each specific card in the UI

That means your card is an object (entity or value object) that has a enumerable state of loading, loaded, error. You can queue on that object in your UI to display a desired representation of that field.

So, both your questions have essentially the same answer. Since you are loading the UI, your state is only relevant to UI objects and not entities that are in the domain model like "Books" that are represented in the backend. Even if you had a front-end representation of "Books" - like in javascript for example - having a loading state still makes more sense in the view object in the view layer.
Note that there's some simplification/flexibility to this answer because it's also valid for your design to have a View that's an aggregate that contains a Books. Those Book objects could have a "loading" state on them. All of this is still restricted to the UI layer though and such an aggregate and it's specific design will depend on the flexibility your UI-framework allows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. According to it and my own toughts for now i think i have two variants:  
- Consider all logic and data on the frontend as application logic and mix all together
- Use application layer classes as a controller to observe\make changes to business layer and pass that changes to the UI. Like using mobx store class and passing a domain repository class to it's constructor and then attaching observables, actions and all that stuff.

Comment: Actually now i'm getting ready to switch redux to mobx cause redux is really the one who is not flexible and with it it's hard to maintain modular structure i've implemented. So i'm investigating data structures to choose the one suitable.  
Sorry i dont know how to make line breaks here.

Comment: I use react and redux as well and redux is very valuable to an application because in the UI, it's important to keep states of your UI components and that's all it does. I would steer away from trying to force DDD into the UI layer, while some of the general concepts and recommendation still apply, it should not get in the way of more important decisions and interactions.